# Select * not returning all columns - Coldfusion / SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I am getting some strange behavior involving database queries that I have never seen before and I'm hoping you can illuminate the issue.

I have a table of data called myTable with some columns; thus far everything involving it has been fine.  Now, I've just added a column called subTitle; and II notice that the `SELECT *` Query that pulls in the data for a given record is not aware of that column (it says the returned query does not have a subTitle column), but if I explicitly name the column (select subTitle) it is.  I thought perhaps that the Coldfusion server might be caching the query so I tried to work around with `cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)#"`  but no dice.

Consider the below code:

---

```
<cfquery name="getSub" datasource="#Application.datasourceName#">
     SELECT   subTitle 
     FROM     myTable
     WHERE    RecordID = '674'
 </cfquery> 

 <cfoutput>#getSub.subTitle#</cfoutput>

 <cfquery name="getInfo" datasource="#Application.datasourceName#">
     SELECT   * 
     FROM     myTable
     WHERE    RecordID = '674'
 </cfquery>  

 <cfoutput>#getInfo.subTitle#</cfoutput>
```

---

Keeping in mind that record 674 has the string "test" in it's subTitle column the about of the above is

test

[[CRASH WITH ERROR]]

This doesn't make sense to me unless SQL Server 2008 has somehow cached the SELECT * query with the previous incarnation of the table, but the strange thing is if I run the query right from within SQL Management Studio there are no problems and it shows all columns with the select *

Frankly this one has me baffled; I know I can get around this by explicitly naming all the desired columns in the select query instead of using * (which is best practice anyway), but I want to understand why this is occurring.

I've worked with SQL Server 2005 for many years and never had something like this happen, which leads me to believe it might involve something new in SQL Server 2008; but then again the fact that the query works fine inside of the management studio doesn't jive with that either.

===UPDATE===

Clearing the Template Cache in the CF admin will solve the issue

Comment: Have you changed the underlying table since the `SELECT *` query was first executed? If so, there's probably something cached, either CF or SQL Server. Trying restarting each service, one at a time and test, to see if it's cached in either place. That noted, `SELECT *` can get you in trouble, generally a better practice to specify columns instead.

Comment: would using `<cfqueryparam>` on 2nd query help?

Comment: I did have that originally, I just dumbed this down to the simplest query for purpose of the example.

Comment: Not sure why but clearing the template cache didn't work for me. I ended up restarting the server.:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, ColdFusion caches the `<cfquery>` SQL string. If the underlying table structure changes, the result might be an exception like you see it.

Work-arounds:

- **Recommended solutiuons:**

  - If you have the development or enterprise version you can view your query cache in the server moniter and clear only the queries there. *(comment from @Dpolehonski, thanks)*
  - Otherwise, click <kbd>Clear Template Cache Now</kbd> in the ColdFusion Administrator (under *Server Settings/Caching*).
    This will invalidate all cached CFML-Templates on the server and CF will re-compile them when necessary.
- **Quick and dirty:**
  Subtly change the query SQL, for example add a space somewhere. When you are on a development machine it's the quickest way to fix the issue.
  This will invalidate the compiled version of this query only and force a re-compile.
  *(Note that removing the subtle change will trigger the error again since the old query text will remain cached.)*
- **Brute-force:**
  Re-start the ColdFusion server. Brutal, but effective.

Comment: Yes it is the coldfusion cache, I just made a slight change to the query (adding Where 1 = 1) and it worked.  Good, at least I understand now; but I thought cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)#" was supposed to circumvent this?

Comment: No, this is just for query *result* caching. The query itself (bound columns and the) like is cached independently. This way CF has something to re-use if the query is executed in a loop, for example.

Comment: That makes sense; is there any way to clear the cache for the queries themselves?

Comment: Got it; you actually clear the template cache in the CF admin

Comment: I always thought this would affect the CFML cache only. But yes, now that makes sense. Looks like I've learned something as well today. :)

Comment: It's nice when things fall into place. CF generates a Java class from the CFML you write, naturally this includes definitive bindings to the SQL queries you make. Clearing the template cache forces a recompile.

Comment: If you have the development or enterprise version you can view your query cache in the server moniter and clear only the queries there.

Comment: @Dpolehonski Thanks for the addition. I've included it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Or the quick and super dirty method:

```
<cfquery name="getInfo" datasource="#Application.datasourceName#">
   SELECT 
     *, #createUUID()# as starQueryCacheFix
   FROM 
     myTable
   WHERE 
   RecordID = '674'
 </cfquery>
```

Don't leave in production code though... it'll obsolete all of the query caching ColdFusion does. I did say it was super dirty ;)

Comment: Wow; that is super dirty indeed ;)